# formData is not a constructor in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

user.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const EditRekko = () => {
const { id } = useParams();
const [rekko, setRekko] = useState({
    product_name:'',
    categoryId:'',
    review:'',
    link:'',
    user_id:'',
    product_img:''
});
const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);

const { product_name, categoryId, product_img, review, link, user_id } = rekko;

const handleChange = e => {
    setRekko({ ...rekko, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

useEffect(() => {
    loadRekko();
}, []);

const handleImageChange = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRekko({ ...rekko, [e.target.name]: e.target.files });
};

const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new formData();
    // for (const file of rekko.product_img) {
    //     formData.append('product_img', file)
    // };
    // formData.append('product_name', rekko.product_name)
    // formData.append('review', rekko.review)
    // formData.append('link', rekko.link)
    // formData.append('categoryId', rekko.categoryId)
    console.log(formData)
    // await Axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/dashboard-rekko/${id}`, formData)
    // toast.success('Rekko Updated');
    // setTimeout(function () {
    //     history.push('/rekko')
    // }, 1500);

};

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='product_name'>Product Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" className="form-control" value={product_name || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='link'>Link:</label>
                <input type="text" name="link" id="link" className="form-control" value={link || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='product_img'>Product Image:</label> <br />
                <input type="file" multiple name="product_img" id="product_img" onChange={e => handleImageChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"> Update Rekko </button>
        </form>
    </>
)
```

}

export default EditRekko

I am getting error that formdata is not constructor while sending using new form data on submit i don't what the mainly problem is it is showing the error which is shown above that form data is not a constructor any help will be appricated

Comment: use capital F `new FormData()`

Comment: Did you mean `new FormData()`? Note the capital `F`. JS is case sensitive, I don't know what `formData` is but you must have defined or imported it somewhere or you would have a different error.

Comment: yes it must be capital F it's silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many others have commented, it should be:

```
// ...
const formData = new FormData();
// ...
```